# While using Selenium, chrome opens with “data;” in the address, although the chromedriver is up to date

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

My project was working fine a few months ago. Although I have just updated the chrome driver used in my project now I still have the issue that the browser starts with "data;" in the address bar and then fails on the timeout condition. I have looked into all the answers regarding this issue and seems like the problems everyone had was that the version of chrome driver used in their project was deprecated (incompatible with their current chrome version) or some other problems in their code which wouldnt be useful in my case since everything was working fine earlier so I know for sure that the problem is with chrome driver. Why do I get that problem even though my chrome driver is up to date and compatible with my chrome version? How can I solve that?
Chrome version: 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver version: 89.0.4389.23

Comment: I'd add a fully reproducible example to the extent possible. Right now we just know what you say and that it doesn't work including no error details.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8061

opening data; is a default behavior of chrome . Please add your code if you have further question